# Please help ID and getting rid of this weed or grass

Tags: grass, weed-control, weeds

This started growing in areas where I added new topsoil and planted new grass seed; likely from seeds infiltrated in the soil or the bale of hay. If left untreated, it will grow up to 3-4ft. The stalk is sturdy and more flat than round.

Will I have to nuke everything including the lawn and re-seed? :( Or is there some sort of selective herbicide the I can use on these?  Any help would be appreciated. I tried tenacity but we are two weeks in now and it didn't help.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is a weed, frequent on vegetable gardens.

But as you see, it growth tall. So just cut lawn regularly and it should disappear. Note: I think it is also an annual herb. So just do not let if to make fruits, and you should not get it back next year. Look also for borders, in order to remove spikes.

Maybe it is *Setaria* ? But I would not bet on my guessing Poaceae family.

Answer (score 1):

I have removed tall grasses like this by selectively use of herbicide. Put the herbicide in a small container. Put on a latex glove with a cotton glove (or even a sock) over it. Dip your covered fingertips in the herbicide and wipe it on the grass leaves. Some people use a 1” paintbrush to paint the leaves. Go back in another week and do the same thing.